# addeventlistener does not work when browsing on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, addeventlistener

Please see the code below:

```
document.getElementById("FirstName").addEventListener("keydown", alphaOnly, false);
document.getElementById("Surname").addEventListener("keydown", alphaOnly, false);

function alphaOnly(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

It works on my local PC using Chrome; IE; Edge and Firefox i.e. the user is unable to enter characters into the two fields.

However, when I browse using my Android (using Chrome or Samsung Internet browser), then I can enter into these fields.  Why is this?

I Googled this and came across this: [AddEventListener works on the browser but does not on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528870/addeventlistener-works-on-the-browser-but-does-not-on-android), however there is no accepted answer.

I have Android 5.0 API 21 if that makes any difference.  Would it make any difference if I used unobtrusive Javascript?

Update

I have just come across this: https://forums.expo.io/t/linking-addeventlistener-url-never-fires-in-android/7442.  Could this be because I have API 21 (see GitHub link).

Comment: Yup, this is a known bug. Some say to use input type tel but the keyboard become numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your Android has no *real* keyboard attached, it has a *virtual* one and it does not fire *key-* events.

Since you're working with `<input>`, listen for `input` event instead of `keydown` or `keyup`. It solves your problem and also helps to handle `paste`.

```js
document.getElementById("FirstName").addEventListener("input", alphaOnly, false);
document.getElementById("Surname").addEventListener("input", alphaOnly, false);


function alphaOnly(event) {
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, '');
}
```

```html
<input id="FirstName"><br>
<input id="Surname">
```

Comment: I don't think that `oninput` is a `cancelable` event. Did you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to block user input, the best option would be the “disabled” attribute (`<input disabled/>`). In JavaScript you can change it as follows:

```
document.getElementById('FirstName').disabled = true;
```

If you want to validate input and accept only some characters:

```js
document.getElementById('FirstName').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  var rgxp = /[^a-z]/g;

  if (rgxp.test(this.value)) {
    // This keeps previous value
    this.value = this.value.replace(rgxp, '');

    // If you do not want to keep old value, use the following:
    // this.value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="FirstName" />
```